# Intellisense not working in Resharper on if snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

It says active hotspot in live template and paints in a red border. Is there a way to make resharper intellisense active inside if snippet?

[image: Intellisense not working]

Answer (score 2):

You see this since ReSharper suggests boolean variables only in that Intellisense popup.

As a solution:
ReSharper | Tools | Templates Explorer | Live Templates tab | C# | Double click on "if" template | Look for "expression" in "Parameters" section | Click on "Suggest variable of System.Boolean" macro text | Look for "Execute basic completion" item and select it | Save the changed template.

[image]